# Button to change next dropdown option that is current month-year

Tags: javascript

I have this dropdown:

```
<div class="defaults_filter_bar">
            <!-- Year filter -->
    <div class="filter_container_temporada">
        <label for="temporada">Temporada</label>
        <select id="filtro_temporada" class='form-control'>
            <option value="all">Totes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  <!-- Month filter -->
  <div class="filter_container_mes">
        <label for="mes">Mes</label>
        <select id="filtro_mes" class='form-control'>
            <option value="all">Tots</option>
            <option value="1">Gener</option>
            <option value="2">Febrer</option>
            <option value="3">Març</option>
            <option value="4">Abril</option>
            <option value="5">Maig</option>
            <option value="6">Juny</option>
            <option value="7">Juliol</option>
            <option value="8">Agost</option>
            <option value="9">Setembre</option>
            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
            <option value="11">Novembre</option>
            <option value="12">Desembre</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

filtro_temporada auto fills with current year, and filtro_mes with current month.

I have this simple code:

```js
function selectNext(){
  var select = document.getElementById('filtro_mes');
  select.selectedIndex++;
}

function selectPrev(){
  var select = document.getElementById('filtro_mes');
  select.selectedIndex--;
}
```

```html
<button id='prev' onclick="selectPrev()">Previous</button>
        <select id="filtro_mes" class='form-control'>
            <option value="all">Tots</option>
            <option value="1">Gener</option>
            <option value="2">Febrer</option>
            <option value="3">Març</option>
            <option value="4">Abril</option>
            <option value="5">Maig</option>
            <option value="6">Juny</option>
            <option value="7">Juliol</option>
            <option value="8">Agost</option>
            <option value="9">Setembre</option>
            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
            <option value="11">Novembre</option>
            <option value="12">Desembre</option>
</select>
<button id='next' onclick="selectNext()">Next</button>
```

Goal:

1. Button to change to next or previous month in the dropdown. Example for july:
   (click and change month dropdown to june) <- July 2022 -> (click and change month dropdown to august).
2. When January is reached and a click on Previous, the year is also changed 1 year less. The same when arrive to December, but 1 year more.
3. The value="all" option it should not appear, it should go to the next month or the previous one, as appropriate.

Comment: how do you display year?

Comment: Auto fill with a Javascript code.